# Why do my images shrink in size instead of moving over when I resize my screen in CSS?

Tags: html, css

So here is my codepen of the site https://codepen.io/designextras/pen/GRoLNOx

Right now whenever I shrink the screen, the red box (one of my svgs) shrinks in size and the box svg also shrinks, so it makes my svg look weird because half of the image is gone vs retaining the entire shape.

I'm trying to replicate the effect of this website when you shrink it
https://clickup.com/

Notice how the gradient background image doesn't shrink when you resize it, it just moves over until it reaches the breaking point, then converts to tablet view.

How can I replicate that effect with my svgs? Note I have two svgs that I added with a ::before and ::after css property

The blue box is supposed to be a gradient colored fancy shape like the clickup example

The red box is supposed to be a svg of a computer illustration

It is proper to implement them with ::before & ::after css properties or should I hard code them as images in my html?

Also, is there a better way to write my html, so that when I shrink the screen it doesn't shrink my svgs awkwardly?

Here is the html, feel free to refactor it

```
                <div class="container">
                    <nav>
                        <div class="navbar-menu">
                            <a href="#" id="logo">Startup</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" id='btn'>Signup</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="home-content">
                            <h1>The Future of Data Tracking</h1>
                            <p>Utilizing our AI powered tracking software we will generate the most accurate results to ensure your business succeeds</p>
                            <div class="input-form">
                                <i class="far fa-envelope-open icon"></i>
                            <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" id="email">
                            </div>
                            <a href="#" class="btn">Get Started</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here is how I added those svg's into my design in the CSS file

```
                .container:before {
                    content: '';
                    display: block;
                    position: absolute;
                    background: url(images/svg-gradient.svg) no-repeat;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    max-width: 60%;
                    top: 0%;
                    right: -5%;
                }

                .container:after {
                    content: '';
                    display: block;
                    position: absolute;
                    background: url(images/dashboard-svg.svg) no-repeat;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    max-width: 50%;
                    top: 20%;
                    right: -10%;
                    transform: rotate(-20deg);
                }
```

I'm trying to make my design mobile responsive, but I'm not sure if I implemented the svgs properly in the CSS

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have a max-width, if the screen width change, then the width box also change. Add a fixed width.

Comment: that did nothing